# Use flask to upload excel file and display data on same page then clear on refreshing the page

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to make a simple flask app that lets you select an excel file and then display the data on the same page upon clicking submit. I'd like to be able to refresh the page and clear the results.

I cannot get the input to display on the page. After clicking submit the html is not being updated. Instead when it receives a GET request it is printing the value of data in the console.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='')
app.secret_key = '123456'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method=='POST':
        file=request.files['file']
        if file.filename != '':
            df = pd.read_excel(file)
            #data=df.to_html()
            data="hello"
            flash("You selected a file!")
            return redirect(url_for("upload", data=data))
    return render_template('upload_test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>From excel:</h1>
    {{ data|safe }}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `{{ data|safe }}`.  Additionally, once the file is selected the return statement is a redirect, thus loading the empty page again.  Perhaps should be a render_template with the data variable passed in.

Comment: @S3DEV sorry that's actually how I wrote it in the original code! I edited the post thanks. It doesn't make a difference in terms of the issue though

Comment: Please read and consider the second part of the comment as well, regarding render_template.

Comment: @S3DEV it has to be a redirect otherwise the data won't clear when you refresh the page